# Set temporary text in a EditText/TextView in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I'm looking to build a simple input form for username/password, and I was wondering if it was possible to mimic the functionality that many websites offer, namely a temporary string within a text input displaying what the field's purpose is. Essentially, I need something like this:

[image]

When the user hasn't yet focused in on the text input, it should display "USERNAME" in a different format. When the user has focused in on the text field, the field is cleared and focus is set and the style is changed. Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at the properties of the edittext  - there is a "hint" property that does just that.

android:hint="Enter Username"

Comment: I _thought_ there was something like this, couldn't find it in the docs for some reason. Fail. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set android:hint="USERNAME" in a particular edittext.

When you will write something in that edittext, it will clear the hint and set your text.Simple...